# Download virtual package

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management, repository

I'm developing the script that downloads all the packages from Ubuntu repository. I know that Ubuntu repository is open via HTTP. So it's possible to download the entire folders (in my particular case `http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty*`). But I would like to download the packages via **apt**. **apt** is good choice because it not only downloads the packages but verifies signatures as well.

The steps are the following:

1. Get names of all the packages via `apt-cache pkgnames`
2. For each name discovered at the previous step execute `apt-get download <package_name>`

It sounds good. But **virtual packages** are the trap.

I'm aware that virtual package is not a package, e.g. not a *deb*-file. It's logical group of normal packages or synonym for the certain normal package (so the commands like `apt-cache show mail-transport-agent` will fail). I suppose that virtual package is actually represented in repository as a file. Such file contains metadata about normal packages the virtual package stands for.

Is it possible to download virtual package metadata file via **apt**? Where is virtual package metadata located in general?